# try/catch is not catching a revert of external contract

Tags: solidity, revert

I have created a contract which allows the input of an external contract address. It is expected that the address is for an ERC20 contract. In order to handle the situation where the user enters a non ERC20 address im using try/catch.

The problem is that if the contract does not have the balanceOf function then it reverts and is not caught by the try/catch. I thought this was the whole point of the try/catch function. To catch reverts from external contract calls!

Below is a small contract which reproduces the issue.

```
contract FailureTest {

    event Success();
    event Failure();

    function doStuff(address target) external {

        try IERC20(target).balanceOf(msg.sender) {
            emit Success();
        } catch {
            emit Failure();
        } 

    }

    interface IERC20 {
        function balanceOf(address) external returns(uint256);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your try/catch block is not catching the revert when calling is because the try/catch block only catches errors that occur within the scope of the block. if the balanceOf function call reverts, the error occurs within the external contract's code, outside of the try/catch block in your own contract's code.

To solve it, you can use the supportsInterface function of the ERC20 contract interface to check if the external contract implements the ERC20 standard. Functional code

```
contract FailureTest {
    event Success();
    event Failure();

    function doStuff(address target) external {
        IERC20 erc20 = IERC20(target);
        if (erc20.supportsInterface(0x36372b07)) {
            
            try erc20.balanceOf(msg.sender) {
                emit Success();
            } catch {
                emit Failure();
            } 
        } else {
            emit Failure();
        }
    }

    interface IERC20 {
        function balanceOf(address) external returns(uint256);
        function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) external view returns (bool);
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is slightly wrong. If `erc20.balanceOf(..)` reverts then `try` will detect the revert status and execute the `catch` block. If the contract doesn't have the `balanceOf` the it could revert depending if the returned value is an empty array or not. ERC20 predate EIP-165 so most ERC-20 tokens do not support being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `call` or `staticcall` to call a function without an external revert bubbling up.

```
bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSelector(IERC20.balanceOf.selector, msg.sender);
(bool success, bytes memory returnData) = target.staticcall(data);
if (success && returnData.length == 32) {
  uint256 result = abi.decode(returnData, (uint256));
  emit Success();
} else {
  emit Failure();
}
```